# SQL compare results of two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with contract and almost the same columns but different kind of contract, and I need to find out what companies didn't had any transactions for more than 6 months.

How I do this:

I can query both tables for correct results, but even if an company has no entry in ContractList1

They may have an Contract in ContractList2.

My SQL to query the results looks like this:

```
Select Company, TransActionDate  
from ContractList1 
group by Company
having max("TransActionDate") <= TO_DATE('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
order by Company asc

Select Company, TransActionDate 
from ContractList2 
group by Company
having max("TransActionDate") <= TO_DATE('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
order by Company asc
```

I can not join them correctly because the Company in ContractList2 has additional values (Countrycode, and id)

Result in ContractList1:

```
COMPANY       TransActionDate
----------+-------------------
AXPO      |   14.05.19
```

Result in ContractList2

```
COMPANY                       TransActionDate
--------------------------+-------------------
AXPO (CZ) [002354.CZ]     |   14.05.19
```

So my question is, how can I unite the two tables to see all companies how
had no transactions for 6 months.

Comment: Are you asking for a UNION??

Comment: Is the (country_code) consistent? Ie. if we remove anything starting from the first left bracket, can we join the tables or some company names can have a bracket in the name or the other table has company names without brackets?

Comment: @Patriot, yes the country_code is consistent. But I don't know how to create a proper sql to remove anything starting from the first left bracket and make a JOIN or a UNION over all Companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same rule works for all company names within `ContractList2` table, I mean, if all company names are seperable by an opening parentheses, then you can use regular expression to split the company string upto `(` character within a subquery containing `UNION` operator as

```
SELECT Company, MAX(TransActionDate) AS TransActionDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Company, TransActionDate FROM ContractList
    UNION 
    SELECT regexp_substr(Company,'[^(]+') AS Company, TransActionDate FROM ContractList2
   )
 GROUP BY Company
HAVING MAX(TransActionDate) <= TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '6' MONTH
```

to get all companies which had no transactions for the last six months.